# Is is true that $|A+B|\ge \min(|A|+|B|-1,p)$ in $\mathbf{Z}_p$?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

For two sets $A,B\subseteq \mathbf {Z}_p $, define
$$A+B:=\{a+b:a\in A,b\in B\}.$$

Note that "+" is performed under $\mathbf {Z}_p$.

For example, let $p=5$, $A=\{1,4\},B=\{2,4\}$. Then $A+B=\{0,1,3\}$.

Is it true that $|A+B|\ge \min(|A|+|B|-1,p)$ in $\mathbf{Z}_p$?

There is a much simpler conclusion that $|A+B|\ge |A|+|B|-1$ in $\mathbf Z$, which can be easily verified. But as for $\mathbf Z_p$, I have no idea...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the Cauchy-Davenport Theorem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_sumset#Cauchy%E2%80%93Davenport_theorem

Here is a proof that came up in Google:

[https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~sk1233/courses/additive-F16/lec1.pdf](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Esk1233/courses/additive-F16/lec1.pdf)